# Group staggered records that are separated by a small time difference

Tags: postgresql, grouping, partitioning

Difficult question to title, but I am trying to replicate what social media or notification feeds do where they batch recent events so they can display “sequences” of actions. For example, if these are "like" records, in reverse chronological order:

```
like_id | user_id |   like_timestamp
--------------------------------
1       | bob     | 12:30:00
2       | bob     | 12:29:00
3       | jane    | 12:27:00
4       | bob     | 12:26:00
5       | jane    | 12:24:00
6       | jane    | 12:23:00
7       | scott   | 12:22:00
8       | bob     | 12:20:00
9       | alice   | 12:19:00
10      | scott   | 12:18:00
```

I would like to group them such that I get the last 3 "bursts" of user likes, grouped (partitioned?) by user. If the "burst" rule is that likes less than 5 minutes apart belong to the same burst, then we would get:

```
user_id | num_likes | burst_start | burst_end
----------------------------------------------
bob     | 3         | 12:26:00    | 12:30:00
jane    | 3         | 12:23:00    | 12:27:00
scott   | 2         | 12:18:00    | 12:22:00
```

`alice`'s like does not get counted because it's part of the 4th most recent batch, and like 8 does not get added to `bob`'s tally because it is 6 minutes before the next one.

I've tried keeping track of bursts with postgres' `lag` function, which lets me mark start and end events, but since like events can be staggered, I have no way of tying a like back to its "originator" (for example, tying id 4 back to 2).

Is this grouping possible? If so, is it possible to keep track of the start and end timestamp of each burst?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a [Range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rangetypes.html) col instead of start and end.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: Please provide table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types & constraints), Postgres version, and what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2c70dd3d72593ac1e29c8e9e27bfcd6e)

```
WITH group_ids AS (   -- 1
    SELECT DISTINCT
        user_id,
        first_value(like_id) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY like_id) AS group_id
    FROM
        likes
    LIMIT 3
)
SELECT 
    user_id,
    COUNT(*) AS num_likes,
    burst_start,
    burst_end
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        -- 4
        first_value(like_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY like_id) AS burst_end,
        first_value(like_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY like_id DESC) AS burst_start
    FROM (
        SELECT
            l.*, gi.group_id,
            -- 2
            lag(like_timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY like_id) - like_timestamp AS diff
        FROM
            likes l 
        JOIN
            group_ids gi ON l.user_id = gi.user_id
    ) s
    WHERE diff IS NULL OR diff <= '00:05:00'  -- 3
) s
GROUP BY user_id, burst_start, burst_end  -- 5
```

1. The CTE is for creating an ordered group id per user_id. So the first user (here the most recent one) gets the lowest `group_id` (which is `bob`). The second user the second highest (`jane`) and so on. This is used to able to work with all likes of a certain user within one partition. This step is necessary because you cannot simply order by `user_id` which would bring alice to the top. The `LIMIT 3` limitates the whole query to the first three users.
2. After joining the calculated user's `group_id` the time differences are calculated using the [`lag()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) which allows you to get the previous value. So it can be used to easily calculate the difference between the current timestamp the the previous one. This happens only within the user's groups.
3. After that the likes that are to much away (more than 5 minutes from the last one) can be removed through the calculated `diff`
4. Then the highest and lower timestamp can be calculated with the `first_value()` window function (ascending and descending order). These mark your `burst_start` and `burst_end`
5. Finally you can group all users and count their records.